# Javapns push notification Invalid Token

Tags: java, ios, push-notification

I am trying to push notification but every time I am getting an invalid token.
The error that I am getting is:

> APNS: [1] Invalid token  javapns.notification.exceptions.ErrorResponsePacketReceivedException: An error response packet was received from the APNS server: APNS: [1] Invalid token]

```
PushNotificationPayload payload=PushNotificationPayload.complex();
payload.addAlert("Hello");

PushedNotifications Notify=Push.alert("hiii", "C:\\Users\\Documents\\PushNotification\\APNS.p12", "123456", true, "Device Token ");/*ra*/
PushedNotification.findSuccessfulNotifications(Notify);

NotificationTest.printPushedNotifications(Notify);

System.out.println("Success "+PushedNotification.findSuccessfulNotifications(Notify));
System.out.println("failed "+PushedNotification.findFailedNotifications(Notify));
```

Answer (score 0):

APNS: [1] Invalid token means the device token you used is invalid. Assuming your app got this device token from Apple (and you didn't use a random token), you are probably using a development token to send push notification to the production push server or vica versa. A device token is only valid in one environment (either sandbox or production).

Comment: I checked the device Token for both production as well as sandbox ,and it is displaying the same error. We are using third party for push notification and i am getting notifications over IOS , but when i am using java (above code) i am getting Device token error .  If it is working in IOS i assume Device Token is correct.